# CSS Animation Not Being Applied

Tags: css, animation, svg

I'm trying to apply an animation to a group within an SVG element. However, I'm finding that it isn't applied or is being overridden, as it's crossed out in Chrome Developer Tools. That said, I have no idea what could be causing it.

Animation code:

```
.ghost {
  animation: float 3s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes float {
  50% {
     transform: translate(100px, 100px);
  }
}
```

I'd post the HTML (the problem might be there) but it's incredibly verbose because of all the SVG paths. Link to a Codepen instead: [ghost](http://codepen.io/helenvholmes/pen/pecdI)

Thank you so much! I have no idea what could be causing the issue at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing your vendor prefixes. Example:

```
.ghost {
  -webkit-animation: float 3s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes float {
  50% {
     -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 100px);
  }
}
```

For an easy fix, try adding **Prefix-free** in CodePen's CSS editor. Here it is with **Prefix-free** enabled:

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/bphillips201/pen/boHJw)

Comment: Thank you so much! I had the prefixes originally but must have had the syntax incorrect. I also wrongly assumed Codepen enabled that off the bat...